# I can't login to admin panel

Tags: magento-1.9

may i have some assistance , I can't login to admin panel and the notification is as follows :

> There has been an error processing your request Exception printing is
>   disabled by default for security reasons. Error log record number:
>   155187663629

may i have some solution please

Comment: please check var/report and there is one file name 155187663629 please paste that error in questions

Answer (score 0):

Check log file with the same number in its filename at `/var/report/`

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/150041)

Comment: I think it does

Answer (score 0):

Run below command:

```
rm -rf var/generation var/cache var/page_cache
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento cache:clean
```

check and confirm.